# Apache/PHP file validation

Tags: php, apache, code-access-security

We have a register with all the files(WEB pages) that should be served from our WEB server.
Can I configure Apache to execute specific script/program which will verify that requested page is registered?
If the requested page is not registered "Page not found" will be presented.

Comment: what do you mean by a 'register'? Why would their be files on your server that you don't want served?

Comment: It concerns me to think that you are ok with allowing unregistered or unapproved files to get on your server in the first instance and that this is not a worry for you.

Comment: The register is a database with file name and location, version, check sum and few other details about the file.  The detail I silted are used to validate the file.

Comment: It is not a matter of week control.  It is more for prevention of using obsolete versions.  I might help against some hacking I guess too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did read your question a couple of times but im still not 100% understanding of what your asking. Please update with some more details.

Apache will send a 404 if a page is not found so im assuming you are allowing arbitrary files on your server (in-dev or versioned files ect) but are trying to find out how to check files or the request against a list of allowed files *before* the file is loaded.

This can be accomplished with PHP and mod_rewrite,

So with PHP and a crude example you could do something like:

```
<?php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); 

if(check_register($path)){
    //load page into buffer
    ob_start();
    require($path);

    echo ob_get_clean();
}else{
    exit(header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found'));
}
?>
```

The `check_register($path)` function would be some mechanism to check whether the file is allowed and would return *true* or *false*, you would need to pass everything to this routing file (index.php) with mod_rewrite so as the request would not load the original file if it was there.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for.  I just need to test and confirm.